# is bad have numerous breakpoints in RWD?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

is a bad practice or not have so many breakpoints to style a page in RWD?
by example, you insert a breakpoint when a element of your page "broke" on layout.

Comment: You may only have breakpoints to target device screens *(resolution-broswer size-device size)* not every time you think your layout "brokes".

Comment: ^ Not true. There is no way in hell you would ever be able to target EVERY device and every screen size. Break points should be at every logical spot where your layout should change due to it no longer making sense to display the content the same as the previous break point.

Comment: A large part of RWD is to be device agnostic.

Comment: @AndrewMcGivery I never say you are able to target every device. I say that referent points to device would be the unique to make breakpoints.

Comment: "You may only have breakpoints to target device screens" <-- keywords in that being "you may only" as in, there is no other possible way to set up your breakpoints.

Comment: *(resolution - browser size - device size - device orientation)* @AndrewMcGivery that's the way media queries should be used I think. As I said again you can set general breakpoints I never said you should target EVERY device exactly.

Answer (score 2):

By targeting numerous break point you create quite a hassle for yourself to chase them since there are so many different sized of screens.

Perhaps a better option would be to target three universal sizes with `@media` queries, and then utilize percentages as best as you can to fill in the gaps with the elements.

Here are two different ways to do `@media` querires in your page:

```
<!-- CSS media query on a link element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />

<!-- CSS media query within a style sheet -->
<style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 719px) and (min-width: 420px){
   .your-class-here {
    display: none;
    }
}
</style>
```

Here are some great locations to get more information on common sizes:

http://cssmediaqueries.com/target/

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

And this article discusses fluid layouts that may help you:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/targeting/

The best option I believe would be to do a fluid layout rather than hard pixel sizes.

Here is a good list of boilerplate sizes courtesy of this page:
http://www.paulund.co.uk/boilerplate-css-media-queries

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 320px)
and (max-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 768px)
and (max-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 768px)
and (max-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 768px)
and (max-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```